Normal derivative of Laplacian fundamental solution
Let $\gamma(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ be the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation, that is for any $\mathbf{x},\,\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^N$
\begin{equation}
\gamma(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=
 \begin{cases}
  -\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|) &\quad\text{if }N=2,\\
  \frac{1}{4\pi\,|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|} &\quad\text{if }N=3.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
In this article, page 6, is stated the following: for $\mathbf{x}\in\Gamma:=\partial\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a domain, if the density $\psi$ and the boundary $\Gamma$ are smooth, we have that
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x})}\int_{\Gamma}\gamma(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\,\psi(\mathbf{y})\,d\sigma(\mathbf{y})=\frac{1}{2}\psi(\mathbf{x})+\int_{\Gamma}\partial_{\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x})}\gamma(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\,\psi(\mathbf{y})\,d\sigma(\mathbf{y})
\end{equation}
where $\partial_{\mathbf{n}(\mathbf{x})}=\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ is the exterior normal on $\Gamma$.
I have no idea on how to prove this fact so any help and suggestion will help. Thank to everyone that will help me.

This strikes me as obviously false, the operator $n(x)\cdot \nabla_x$ is independent of the integration variable $y$ and can thus be moved in and out of the integral at will.... the above equation would reduce to the trivial $\psi\equiv 0$. Whatever point the author is trying to illustrate, he is doing so poorly.....
